# Connection dropouts with RealTek RTL8188CE

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, realtek

I'm an Ubuntu rookie with an unresolved wireless internet connection issue. I've spent a lot of time fiddling around in my never-ending quest to get my connection working properly, but my inexperience is beginning to show and I need a little extra help.

The issue in brief: slow speed (Ookla clocks in at ~5-8Mbps download speed - it should be ~20) and connection dropouts occur every ten minutes.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic

I've done some homework and tried a lot of solutions from these forums. I think ultimately the problem is going to be with the driver rtl8192ce. I've tried changing it to rtl8188ce using FreedomBen's [tutorial](https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver), but I can't fathom how to use script for the automatic installation (I have problems with manual installation too, but I don't want to ask two questions in one post, so I'll save them for later). Can anyone help me out? I think I have the .zip downloaded if that's important.

I've included outputs to various Terminal commands below that may also prove helpful.

lshw

```
description: Wireless interface
            product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: bc:ee:7b:e4:e8:22
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=3.13.0-32-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.41 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

lsmod | grep rtl

```
rtl8192ce              52806  0 
rtl_pci                26314  1 rtl8192ce
rtlwifi                52835  2 rtl_pci,rtl8192ce
rtl8192c_common        47340  1 rtl8192ce
mac80211              546051  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ce
cfg80211              409394  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
```

iwconfig

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"virginmedia0147357"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: A0:21:B7:D6:9B:E2   
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

lspci

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter (rev 01)
```

Sorry if I've missed something obvious, I'm green as grass but, as you can see, willing to suffer a lot of hassle to avoid returning to Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the driver package:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove linux-firmware-nonfree && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

then reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Save any unsaved work before you start as the last command will reboot.

Open a terminal to copy and paste the following commands one line at a time to install the driver. Press enter after each command line. Do not close the terminal untill you are completely finished with the installation.

**first command:**

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

**second command:**

```
cd && git clone https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver.git
```

**third command:**

```
cd rtl8188ce-linux-driver && sudo make
```

**fourth command:**

```
sudo make install && sudo reboot
```

**notes**

When it asks to change branches type for you after the third command, select "y" and at the end of the fourth command it will say something about turing power-save mode off, just select "n" or no because that is not an option for this driver in this version of ubuntu anyway but if you select yes it won't matter you'll just recieve an error that is of no consequence.

---

**For 16.04**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192ce
sudo modprobe -r rtlwifi
sudo modprobe rtl8192ce
```

Comment: 3rd cmd: it can't find that `rtl_hal_pwrseqcmdparsing( )`. See
`
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/home/gsamaras/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/rtl8188ee/hw.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/home/gsamaras/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/rtl8188ee] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-58-generic
make[1]: *** [default] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/gsamaras/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/rtl8188ee
make: *** [all] Error 2` I was said to follow this when asked [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/780507/windows-vs-linux-when-it-comes-to-internet).

Comment: And then the make in the 4th command also fails.

Comment: @gsamaras If you are using 16.04, follow the updated instructions.

Comment: mchid I am in 14.04.

Comment: @gsamaras If you continue to have issues, please update your previous question with the info gathered by following the instructions from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos